# Find position from row and tag with another table?

Tags: position

I have table where one of my field is 40 char long and the values are coming like this

```
00A000GB000C000000000F000000D0000000000E
```

now I need to find out the position for each character populated and join with another table, another table has field call position. For Example

from the field above, A is 3rd position, G is 7th position, B is 8
so I have to find the position for the fields populated(<>0) and then join with another table.

Please let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: I think you need to clarify a bit, I'm not even sure if you're talking about SQL or something else...?

Answer (score 0):

I think the community will need some more information to help with this question.

A couple questions I have when looking at this is:

1. What type of database are you using?
2. Are you looking to actually JOIN a table with another or are you talking about populating another table with data?  If it is a join what type of data are you using to link the 2 tables?
3. Are you wanting to do this with SQL?
4. What programming language are you working with?

It sounds to me like you are going to need to do some programming to handle this one.  Not knowing the answers to the above questions I am taking a stab at things and would recommend extracting the data from the database, processing the data to find the position, then select from the second table based on your processed data.